# How to call local variable outside of function using OOP in Python?

Tags: python

I know there's multiple ways of calling a variable outside of a function, but I'm trying to do this using OOP. Here's my code:

```
import re
import os.path as p
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

def main(file_in):

    v_pat = re.compile(r"^v\s[\s\S]*")
    vertices = ['None']
        
    with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
        for line in f_in:
            v = v_pat.match(line)

            if v:
                vertices.append(v.group())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_in = sys.argv[1]
    main(file_in)
```

I'd like to call the vertices array outside of the function using OOP. What would my code look like if I were to implement that?

Comment: What do you mean by "call"ing it? You can't call a list

Comment: Do you want to return it?

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do. What is not "OOP" about the multiple ways you know?

Comment: So in that case, it is probably best to return it. If you don't want to do that, you can make it a global variable, or a class variable of a global class. But returning it is probably best.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you don't want to return the list, but if you just want to make that function into a class and have that list as an attribute you can try this

```
import re
import os.path as p
import sys
from contextlib import contextmanager
import os

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.v_pat = re.compile(r"^v\s[\s\S]*")
        self.vertices = ['None']
    def doStuff(self, file_in):
        with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
            for line in f_in:
                v = self.v_pat.match(line)
                if v:
                    self.vertices.append(v.group())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_in = sys.argv[1]
    myClass = MyClass()
    myClass.doStuff(file_in)
    print(myClass.vertices)
```

Comment: i would make a function for each array
or return all of them and use the ones i need